# getting image src in php

Tags: php, image, src

how to get image source from an img tag using php function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider taking a [look at this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

I'm not sure if this is an accepted method of solving your problem, but check this code snippet out:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 8):

Or, you can use the built-in DOM functions (if you use PHP 5+):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img");
for ($i=0; $i < $imgs->length; $i++) {
    $img = $imgs->item($i);
    $src = $img->getAttribute("src");
    // do something with $src
}
```

This keeps you from having to use external classes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from URL or file

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
   echo $element->src.'<br>';
}

// Find all links 

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
   echo $element->href.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$path1 = 'http://example.com/index.html';//path of the html page
$file = file_get_contents($path1);
$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($file);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($links as $link)
{    
    $re = $link->getAttribute('src');
    $a[] = $re;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => demo/banner_31.png
    [1] => demo/my_code.png
)
```